# How to add rows dynamically in a repeater control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

[image]

While click Add button i need to add the rows dynamically

Comment: Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961900/jquery-clone-table-row

Comment: [Dynamically adding / removing rows in ASP.NET Repeater](http://xaeryan.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/dynamically-adding-removing-textboxes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this - [Dynamically adding / removing rows in ASP.NET Repeater (or other control) - using custom collections](http://xaeryan.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/dynamically-adding-removing-textboxes.html)

Comment: Look huMpty duMpty was faster

Comment: Also, when you just posting a link it can go under comments!!! Please have a [look](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('table').append('<tr>...</tr>');
```