# Dynamically append rows to a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jinja2

I am able to append table rows dynamically but encounter a problem when I am embedding values.

I am using jinja2.

Example:

My input by textbox is like this:

Date From: 20130201     * id is **"txtStartDate"**

To: 20130205    * id is **"txtEndDate"**

Number: 10  * id is **"txtAllotNumber"**

Output should be like this:

□  20130201   10   blank
 □  20130202   10   blank
 □  20130203   10   blank
 □  20130204   10   blank
 □  20130205   10   blank

- □ is a checkbox
- the blank part should be edited also.

This is the output which is incorrect:

20130210    20130205    10  blank

This is how I am appending the table:

```
            var chkflg = "";
            var newtrtag = '<tr class="centertext getData">';
            newtrtag += '<td class="checkGet" style="padding-left: 20px;"><input class="chkGetData" type="checkbox" name="del_param" value="{{stay_ymd}},{{allot_number}},{{delete_flag}},{{re_release_ymd}}"></td>';
            newtrtag += '<input type="hidden" id="quantity{{stock_count}}" name="quantity{{stock_count}}" value="{{allot_number}}">';
            newtrtag += '<input type="hidden" name="save[{{stock_count}}]" value="{{stay_ymd}},{{allot_number}},{{delete_flag}},{{re_release_ymd}}">';
            newtrtag += '{% set delete_flag_val = '0'%}';
            newtrtag += '{% if delete_flag %}';
            newtrtag += '{% set delete_flag_val = '1' %}';
            newtrtag += '{% else%}';
            newtrtag += '{% endif %}';
            newtrtag += '<input type="hidden" id="delflag{{stock_count}}" name="delflag{{stock_count}}" value="{{delete_flag_val}}">';
            newtrtag += '<input type="hidden" id="rerel{{stock_count}}" name="rerel{{stock_count}}" value="{{re_release_ymd}}">';
            newtrtag += '<td style="width:70%;">'+ $("#txtStartDate").val() +' </td>';
            newtrtag += '<td style="width:70%;">'+ $("#txtEndDate").val() +' </td>';
            newtrtag += '<td style="width:70%;">'+ $("#txtAllotNumber").val() +' </td>';
            newtrtag += '{% set delete_flag_chk = "" %}';
            newtrtag += '{% if delete_flag == True %}';
            newtrtag += '{% set delete_flag_chk = "Released" %}';
            newtrtag += '{% else%}';
            newtrtag += '{% set delete_flag_chk = "Unreleased" %}';
            newtrtag += '{% endif %}';
            newtrtag += '<td class="colStatus">{{delete_flag_chk}}</td>';
            newtrtag += '<td class="releaseDate">{{re_release_ymd}}</td>';
            newtrtag += '</tr>';
            $("#list_body").append(newtrtag);
```

The whole tbody code is like this where I am adding it:

```
<tbody id="list_body">
{% set stock_count = 0 %}
{% for row in release_stock_list %}
    <tr class="centertext getData">
        <td class="checkGet" style="padding-left: 20px;"><input class="chkGetData" type="checkbox" name="del_param" value="{{row.stay_ymd}},{{row.allot_number}},{{row.delete_flag}},{{row.re_release_ymd}}"></td>
        <input type="hidden" id="quantity{{stock_count}}" name="quantity{{stock_count}}" value="{{row.allot_number}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="save[{{stock_count}}]" value="{{row.stay_ymd}},{{row.allot_number}},{{row.delete_flag}},{{row.re_release_ymd}}">
        {% set delete_flag_val = '0'%}
        {% if row.delete_flag %}
            {% set delete_flag_val = '1' %}
        {% else%}
        {% endif %}
        <input type="hidden" id="delflag{{stock_count}}" name="delflag{{stock_count}}" value="{{delete_flag_val}}">
        <input type="hidden" id="rerel{{stock_count}}" name="rerel{{stock_count}}" value="{{row.re_release_ymd}}">
        <td class="colDate">{{row.stay_ymd}}</td>
        <td class="colAmount">{{row.allot_number}}</td>
        {% set delete_flag_chk = "" %}
        {% if row.delete_flag == True %}
            {% set delete_flag_chk = "Released" %}
        {% else%}
            {% set delete_flag_chk = "Unreleased" %}
        {% endif %}
        <td class="colStatus">{{delete_flag_chk}}</td>
        <td class="releaseDate">{{row.re_release_ymd}}</td>
        {% set stock_count = stock_count + 1 %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this sort of thing is done by cloning existing rows; you might have a hidden template row you'd clone.  This avoid all sorts of issues such as yours.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961900/jquery-clone-table-row).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Do you want sample code?  Or do you want to be able to format something in your dynamically-added rows?

Comment: I want to format it the same as on my template. Like my second code above.