# jQuery cloning of table row breaks button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a html table (Bootstrap 3) which has a button in its last `td` of each row. This button has a class `btn-add-row`. In my Javascript I use (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961934/2976720) question):

```
$('.btn-add-row').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

Now, the row which is cloned also contains that specific button. It copies the button without issue, but when you click the button in the row which was added, the javascript is not executed. The copied button does have the class `btn-add-row`, and clicking buttons which were originally already on the page still work.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options here.
First to add click handler for cloned row

```
function clickHandler() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  $clone.find('.btn-add-row').click(clickHandler);
  $clone.find('input').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
}
$('.btn-add-row').click(clickHandler);
```

And the other to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$( "table" ).on( "click", ".btn-add-row", clickHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my question. I forgot how to add the click handler for a cloned element, so I used your first suggestion which works great.

Comment: Thats great, but also read about event delegation it has some performance advantageю

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I read through the documentation you provided and I understand event propagation better now. I'll change it in my project. Thank you again!