# how to clone a tr with it's td inside it with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, clone

I am using this ajax success to clone a `tr` with its `td` inside it:

```
success: function(response){
    var file = $(".drop-file").clone();
    file.html(response);        
    $('.myfiles').append(file);
}
```

This is my html structure:

```
<tr class="drop-file">
    <td class="myFiles"></td>
</tr>
```

At this moment, this is the output:

```
<tr class="drop-file">
    <td class="myFiles">
        <tr class="filename">1.png</tr>
        <tr class="filename">2.png</tr>
        <tr class="filename">3.png</tr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But it should be like this:

```
<tr class="drop-file">
    <td class="myFiles">1.png</td>
    <td class="myFiles">2.png</td>
    <td class="myFiles">3.png</td>
</tr>
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: what is content of **response**?

Comment: the name of a file, like `1.png`

Comment: Only text `1.png, 2.png, ...` or contain html `<td>1.png</td>...`?

Comment: You're appending a `<tr>` to a `<td>`. That makes no sense. The parent of a `<tr>` has to be the `<table>` (or a section of a table like `<tbody>`).

Comment: no only text. Php echo looks like this: ` $file = $_FILES['dropImage']['name'];
   echo $file;`

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the result you claim you're getting. It should produce `<tr class="drop-file"><td class="myFiles"><tr class="drop-file">1.png</tr></td></tr>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Clone table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961900/jquery-clone-table-row)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't clone the `<tr>`, just clone one of the `.myFiles` elements, and append it to `.drop-files`.

```
var file = $(".myFiles").clone();
file.html(response);        
$('.drop-files').append(file);
```

Comment: In this case, only the `td` will be cloned. But a complete row with it's `td` inside it should be clonded

Comment: Please edit the question, and show what should be in the DOM before and after the AJAX request. Because it's not really clear. When you do `file.html(response)`, that just puts a single filename into the element that you cloned. If you clone a `<tr>`, you need something like `.html("<td>" + response + "</td>")` because a TR has to contain TD elements. And why are you cloning a row along with its TRs if you're just going to overwrite them?